# Estimating separate regressions and generating predictions by group for different data sets

Tags: r, lapply

I want to use the same regression model for each group (id) using data "train" and use the estimated coefficients to create predicted values in data "test". I can do it using a loop, but how can I do it with `lapply` or something else?

```
train <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = rnorm(100), id = rep(c('a', 'b'), 50))
test <- data.frame(x = 1:50, id = rep(c('a', 'b'), 25))
for (i in c('a', 'b')){
  model <- lm(y ~ x, data = subset(train, id == i))
  test$pred[test$id == i] <- predict(model, subset(test, id == i))
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `lapply` or "something else"? Is there a problem with the current code?

Comment: @MrFlick, I use the loop above for a large data set, and it takes long. So I am wondering if there is a faster method that can be used instead.

Comment: If speed if your only concern, then lapply isn’t going to be any faster. If your data is large consider using something like data.table for your data instead where you can subset your data more quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still insist on using `lapply` you can use the following solution:

```
test <- test[order(test$id),]

test$pred <- unlist(lapply(split(test, test$id), function(dt) {
  model <- lm(y ~ x, data = subset(train, id == dt$id))
  dt$pred <- predict(model, dt)
}))
```